# How do I programmatically check if a url needs unescaping in python?

Tags: python, escaping

Working on a small web spider in python, using the lxml module I have a segment of code which does an xpath query of the document and places all the links from 'a href' tags into a list. what I'd like to do is check each link as it is being added to the list, and if it is needed, unescape it. I understand using the urllib.unquote() function, but the problem I'm experiencing is that the urllib method throws an exception which I believe is due to not every link that is passed to the method needs unescaping. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's the code I have so far:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from lxml.html import parse, tostring

class Crawler():

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.links = []
    def crawl(self):

        doc = parse("http://" + self.url).getroot()
        doc.make_links_absolute(self.url, resolve_base_href=True)
        for tag in doc.xpath("//a"):
            old = tag.get('href')
            fixed = urllib.unquote(old)
            self.links.append(fixed)
        print(self.links)
```

Comment: You could put a try except around it

Comment: Do you have an example of a URI that raises an exception? I have tried some with and without escaping, and can't get it to fail.

Comment: Unescaping a URL that doesn't need it shouldn't raise an exception - something else is wrong here.  Can you post an example of a URL that causes an exception?

Comment: use `doc.xpath("//a[@href]")` to exclude `a` elements without `href` attribute.

Comment: First rule of asking questions: include the stack trace you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unquote` doesn't throw exceptions because of URLs that don't need escaping.  You haven't shown us the exception, but I'll guess that the problem is that `old` isn't a string, it's probably `None`, because you have an `<a>` tag with no `href` attribute.

Check the value of `old` before you try to use it.

Comment: This was it. I took a second look at the stack trace, and it was referencing a 'None' object. I made the changes to the xpath query as noted in the above comments, working great now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
url.find('%') > -1
```

or wrap `urllib.unquote` in a `try`..`except` clause.

Comment: The lack of a % does not actually cause unquote() to raise an exception.

Comment: I think `'%' in url` would be slightly more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Although I don't have a url which causes an exception. So this is just hypothesis at this point. See if this approach works.

```
from urllib import unquote

#get url from your parse tree.
url_unq = unquote(url or '')
if not url_unq:
    url_unq = url
```

See if this works? It would be great if you could give an actual example of the URL which causes exception. What Exception? Could you post the StackTrace?

Worst-case you could always use a `try-except` around that block & go about your business.